# ReactDOM.render creates readonly Element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I was trying to create a react element with below javascript code.

```
  var root = React.createElement('MyfolderShow', { myfolder_path: "/folder1 , update: "true", folder: "folder1"});
  ReactDOM.render(root, document.getElementById('Folders'));
```

But when I run this it creates a empty component. 
I'm using react-rails.

Comment: Are you missing a `"` after `/folder1`?

Comment: Anyways. found the issue. It's like you can't access JSX classes from Javascript Code :/